# Can I define a constexpr anonymous/unnamed variable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

By mistake, I wrote something along the lines of `constexpr bool{};`, and while GCC and Clang rejected this, MSVC was more than happy to compile it (see [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4mackc)). From my understanding, functions (and thus constructors) evaluated at compile time cannot have side effects, therefore this can never have any effect, but is it indeed ill-formed?

(In my experience, MSVC tends to be wrong, but in this specific case I didn’t find where the standard forbids this.)

Comment: Baffling!  For what it's worth, MSVC seems equally content with just `constexpr bool;`.   I don't think this has anything to do with functions or side-effects.

Comment: Nothing is compiled. It is thrown out by the compiler as useless. But good question, what does the standard say? `gcc error expected primary-expression before...` with google is unclear.

Comment: @DrewDormann `constexpr;` is also fine! Even with `/permissive-`. This should be clearly ill-formed. And `constexpr bool{} constexpr;` gives me this not quite related error message: "*<source>(2): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'*"

Comment: In C++26, you may be able to create a nearly-anonymous variable, though not `constexpr`: see [P2169R4: _A nice placeholder with no name_](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P2169R4.pdf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's just not valid syntax. It is "forbidden" by the standard by virtue of not being a possible grammar production.

A declaration such as

```
constexpr bool b{};
```

is a *simple-declaration* and has the syntax *decl-specifier-seq* *init-declarator-list*(opt) `;` (see C++17 [dcl.dcl]/1). The keyword `constexpr` is a *decl-specifier*, and so is `bool` (although only some decl-specifiers have an effect on the type; `bool` does, but `constexpr` does not).

The rest of the declaration, `b{}`, is an *init-declarator*, which consists of a *declarator* plus an optional *initializer*, which in this case is `{}`. (See [dcl.decl]/1.) The declarator is `b`. In general, a declarator must contain an identifier such as `b`. See [dcl.decl]/4.

There is a similar grammar production called an *abstract-declarator* which lacks an identifier (See [dcl.name]/1). Abstract declarators are allowed in particular contexts, such as when writing down a *type-id*, or in a *parameter-declaration-clause* (function parameters are allowed to be unnamed). However, an *init-declarator* must contain a *declarator*, not an *abstract-declarator*.

There is no other grammar production that would match `constexpr bool{};` either.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just `bool{};` is legal due to it being a _type-id_. But a `constexpr` is not allowed in a _type-specifier-seq_, therefore it must be a  _decl-specifier-seq_, which then again results in the statement being a _simple-declaration_.

But according to [dcl.type]/1, `const` as being a _cv-qualifier_ is allowed in a _type-specifier-seq_, hence `const bool{};` is a possible grammar production? I am sure there is an error in my reasoning, as Clang and GCC [disagree once more](https://godbolt.org/z/9A7ebM).

Comment: @EmmaX A function-style cast such as `bool{}` requires the type to be a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier*. See [expr.post]/1, [expr.type.conv]. This is more restrictive than a *type-id*. `const bool` does not fit into the grammar of a *simple-type-specifier*. To use a general *type-id* for a cast, you must enclose it with parentheses, or use a C++-style cast.